# Como evitar un rango de fechas si en medio hay dias deshabilitados?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Tengo un datepicker (https://react-day-picker.js.org/) con `mode=range` y ciertas fechas se encuentran deshabilitadas. Si yo selecciono un rango de fechas, y en medio de este hay fechas deshabilitadas, el rango se selecciona sin problemas.

Yo quiero evitar esto, quisiera que la ultima fecha del rango sea un día antes de la primer fecha deshabilitada.

Por ejemplo: Elijo el rango del 10 al 20 de enero, pero el 15 de enero se encuentra deshabilitada, entonces el rango debe convertise automaticamente del 10 de enero al 14 de enero.

Existe alguna forma de hacer esto pasando alguna prop al componente?

```
const defaultSelected = {
    from: undefined,
    to: undefined,
  };

  const [range, setRange] = useState(defaultSelected);

<DayPicker
    disabled={disabledDates}
    fromDate={new Date()}
    mode="range"
    numberOfMonths={2}
    selected={range}
    onSelect={setRange}
  />
```

Comment: Hola M.G, aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primer medalla!

Comment: @MarcePuente Gracias! Es una sugerencia, o tiene que ver con que a mi pregunta le falta información? Ya hice la recorrida y me dio una medalla que todavía no veo reflejada al lado de mi avatar.

Comment: No puedo confirmar si falta información, porque no manejo reacts, a mi me parece que está muy bien formulada... lo de la medalla, es raro, supongo que si sales y vuelves a entrar...

Comment: no existe tal prop, tendrias que crear algo que comprueve dicho rango ...